# What is the difference between the predict and predict_on_batch methods of a Keras model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

According to the keras [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/):

```
predict_on_batch(self, x)
Returns predictions for a single batch of samples.
```

However, there does not seem to be any difference with the standard `predict` method when called on a batch, whether it being with one or multiple elements.

```
model.predict_on_batch(np.zeros((n, d_in)))
```

is the same as

```
model.predict(np.zeros((n, d_in)))
```

(a `numpy.ndarray` of shape `(n, d_out`)

Comment: What size is the array? `predict` takes an argument `batch_size`, which defaults to 32 if not set. If n <= 32, those two function calls should do the same.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The difference lies in when you pass as `x` data that is larger than one batch.

[`predict`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1476) will go through all the data, *batch by batch*, predicting labels.
It thus internally does the splitting in batches and feeding one batch at a time.

[`predict_on_batch`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1612), on the other hand, assumes that the data you pass in is exactly one batch and thus feeds it to the network. It won't try to split it (which, depending on your setup, might prove problematic for your GPU memory if the array is very big)

Comment: Ok, thx. The batch_size is actually about the same thing as SGD's (and its variants) minibatches. Also confirmed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221886/how-to-set-mini-batch-size-in-sgd-in-keras).

Comment: Yes, wherever you see "batch" the common assumption is that you're talking of minibatches of the learning algorithm.

Comment: No clue, never ran into that use-case yet

Answer (score 8):

It seems predict_on_batch is a lot faster compared to predict if executed on a single batch.

- batch & model information

  - batch shape: (1024, 333)
  - batch dtype: float32
  - model parameters: ~150k
- timeit result:

  - predict: ***~1.45 seconds***
  - predict_on_batch: ***~95.5 ms***

In summary, predict method has extra operations to ensure a collection of batches are processed right, whereas, predict_on_batch is a lightweight alternative to predict that should be used on a single batch.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add something that does not fit in a comment. It seems that `predict` check <s>carefully</s> the output shape:

```
class ExtractShape(keras.engine.topology.Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        return keras.backend.sum(x, axis=0)
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

a = keras.layers.Input((None, None))
b = ExtractShape()(a)
m = keras.Model(a, b)
m.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy')
A = np.ones((5,4,3))
```

Then:

```
In [163]: m.predict_on_batch(A)
Out[163]: 
array([[5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.],
       [5., 5., 5.]], dtype=float32)
In [164]: m.predict_on_batch(A).shape
Out[164]: (4, 3)
```

But:

```
In [165]: m.predict(A)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-c5ba5fc88b6e> in <module>()

----> 1 m.predict(A)

~/miniconda3/envs/ccia/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1746         f = self.predict_function
   1747         return self._predict_loop(f, ins, batch_size=batch_size,
-> 1748                                   verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
   1749 
   1750     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

~/miniconda3/envs/ccia/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _predict_loop(self, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1306                         outs.append(np.zeros(shape, dtype=batch_out.dtype))
   1307                 for i, batch_out in enumerate(batch_outs):
-> 1308                     outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out
   1309                 if verbose == 1:
   1310                     progbar.update(batch_end)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,3) into shape (5,3)
```

I am not sure if this is a bug really.

Comment: I don't get where that `(5,3)` comes from. You have 5 elements in your batch, but why is the second dimension disappearing?

Comment: @GPhilo Look at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1336 the list of outputs is pre-computed and the output shape is sliced assuming the first dimension is the "batch index".

Comment: Ok now I get your point. I think `predict` has to check the output's shape because it needs to put all results together and return them all at the same time, so it preallocates the space for that. On the other hand, `predict_batch` only needs to return the result of one evaluation run, so it doesn't need to care about the shape of what's returned. So yes, in case of custom layers that do not produce one result per batch, `predict` won't work. I also don't think this is a bug, though..

Comment: @GPhilo The reason I think is a bug is that the method `compute_output_shape` is not used. `predict` is performing a shape check just as a byproduct of the pre-allocation of the list `outs` using the shape of the first batch. It seems that the user is responsible for treating the first dimension appropriately, and that includes to define correctly the method `compute_output_shape`and return a tensor of that shape. Also,  `predict` and `predict_on_batch` should behave in a similar way in the case of having less-than `batch_size` samples.